# How to connect the Data Modeler with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

I want to document a SQL Server 2008 database. I have been asked for the Diagram and the specifications of the tables, fields, data type, etc. (Data Dictionary).

The problem is that I can not find a program that suits my requirements. The Erwin Data Modeler has a reverse engineering tool, but it is not useful because it does not allow me to specify only the tables that I want to diagram, at the very same request the schemas (But it is in this program that I am asked to do the diagramming) . SQL Server Management Studio is not an option because it is the same that manages the Databases (it implies modifying the DB in some way) and it is not very flexible with the choice of tables.

So I resorted to Data Modeler works perfectly with an Oracle database, you can make diagrams, generate scripts (the latter helped me to pass diagrams to Erwin), and even generate documentation of objects, etc. But I have not been able to connect it to SQL Server 2008 to do the same thing I did with Oracle. I downloaded the jtds-1.2.jar to make the connection but I do not know exactly how to do it.

[image]

In summary I need a program that allows me to choose the tables to which I want to diagram (These are things that are achieved with the Data Modeler) and then be able to open them in the Erwin (With the script that generates the latter) which is the target program. And also the field documentation, although this is a secondary issue to the question.

It would be helpful if you know of any other method, program or procedure.

Comment: you need jtds-1.3.jar and then add it to sql developer preferences, third party jdbc in preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download from sourceforge jTDS v1.3 or 1.3.1

get the JAR out of the zip

add it to your sqldev folder

open preferences in the tool, and go to third party drivers, under database page i think, and then when you get to connection dialog, there will be a SQL Server and Sybase connection type

i talk about this in more detail [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-supports-db2-sybase-mysql-access-and-teradata/)

You can connect to a SQL 2008 db and RE the databases into one or more data models, and then generate data dictionary reports and DDL scripts. And a lot more..get v4.2 if you want to generate HTML reports that include the diagrams themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to connect to the Data Modeler, not with the sqldeveloper.he downloaded the driver and I copied it to the program address, in this case the sqldeveloper, but I get the following error: "`I / O Error : SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded Check the java.library not loaded Check the java.library.path system property.`"

Comment: sql developer, sql develper data modeler - the 3rd party jdbc driver stuff is the same. sounds like you're trying to use windows authentication instead of sql server - that's fine. you just need to do this https://community.oracle.com/message/12409300#12409300

Comment: Thank you!!, they should explain that "little" detail in their official pages, thus avoiding many head breaks.

Comment: which part, the bit on Windows authentication and the dll?

Comment: `"Took the ntlmauth.dll in the jtds-1.3.1-dist\x64\SSO folder and put it into the datamodeler\jdk\jre\bin folder"` . This is the answer of your link. "Little datail". But it solved me the problem.